# Convert ggplot object to plotly in shiny application

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to convert a ggplot object to plotly and show it in a shiny application. But I encountered an error "no applicable method for 'plotly_build' applied to an object of class "NULL""

I was able to return the ggplot object to the shiny application successfully,

```
output$plot1 <- renderplot({
   gp <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = cyl)) + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y~x) + geom_point() + theme_gdocs()
})
```

but somehow plotly cannot convert it.

My code looks like this

```
output$plot2 <- renderplotly({
   gp <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = cyl)) + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y~x) + geom_point() + theme_gdocs()
   ggplotly()
})
```

Comment: use renderPlotly instead

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(  
titlePanel("Plotly"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(),
mainPanel(
  plotlyOutput("plot2"))))
  
server <- function(input, output) {

output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = cyl)) + 
      geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y~x) + 
      geom_point() + 
      theme_gdocs())
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sorry about that. give it another try.

Comment: It is working now. Actually both ggplotly or print(ggplotly()) work fine. I noticed that I need to restart shiny server in order to make the change (from ggplot to plotly) take effect. I don't know whether this is normal or not but it did cause some inconsistent observation when runing shiny in Rstudio vs on web server.

Comment: I had to restart the server as well, yes.  However, my plot output is not going to the application in the browser, but is instead rendering in the Rstudio's Viewer tab...any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here. it is going to the Rstudio's plot instead of browser. useless

Comment: Same here, following @TrivialSpace's tip

Comment: The answer pasted into my Rstudio (lastest version) does not work

Answer (score 25):

If it is rendering in the RStudio pane instead of the app, do make sure that you are using `plotlyOutput` in the UI section as well as `renderPlotly` in the server section.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Comment: Thanks! exactly what i was missing. This is in the example above but skimmed over it.