# How to unisolate an particular input inside an isolate() function in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'am on the process of building a shiny dashboard about the electoral behavior, 
I have 3 widgets: Gender, Region and Political parti, the user can choose a gender or/and a region or/and political parti and the dashborad will show a plot based on the input chosen, and I put a radio buttom inside the box of the plot that allows to the user to choose the type of the stacked bar chart: position="stack" or "fill", I add an actionbuttom and the isolate() function so that all the inputs on the page do not send updates to the server until the button is pressed. However I want the radio buttom that indicate the type of the stacked bar chart not to be isolated: this is the code R that i used:

Data frame

```
       pff <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
                 REGION Q99 Q101
              Tunis  Nahdha Femme
              Tunis Jabha Femme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis        Nahdha Femme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
              Tunis           CPR Femme
              Tunis        Nahdha Femme
              Tunis        Autres Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis        Nahdha Homme
              Tunis Jabha Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis        Nahdha Homme
              Tunis        Nahdha Femme
              Tunis JabhaChaabia Homme
              Tunis        Autres Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
              Tunis Jabha Femme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
              Tunis        Autres Homme
              Tunis        Nahdha Femme
              Tunis        Nahdha Homme
              Tunis        Autres Femme
              Tunis Jabha Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis           CPR Femme
              Tunis        Nahdha Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Tunis        Nahdha Homme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
              Tunis           CPR Homme
              Tunis           CPR Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
              Tunis        Autres Homme
              Tunis        Nahdha Homme
              Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
              Tunis        Nahdha Femme
              Tunis        Autres Femme
              Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
              Ariana        Nahdha Femme
              Ariana           CPR Femme
              Ariana        Nahdha Femme
              Ariana  Nepasvoter Homme
              Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
              Ariana           CPR Homme
              Ariana  Nepasvoter Homme
              Ariana        Nahdha Homme
              Ariana  Nepasvoter Femme
              Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
              Ariana           CPR Homme
              Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
              Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
              Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
              Ariana           CPR Femme
              Ariana        Nahdha Femme
              Ariana           CPR Femme
              Ariana        Nahdha Homme
              Ariana        Nahdha Homme
              Ariana           CPR Homme
              Ariana        Nahdha Homme
              Ariana  Nepasvoter Homme
              Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
              Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
              Ariana        Nahdha Homme    ')
```

server

```
     library(shiny)
     library(ggplot2)
     library(ggalt)
     library(dplyr)
     library(foreign)
     library(plotly)
     library(scales)

     shinyServer(function(input, output) {
     dataa<-reactive({
     within(as.data.frame(pff), 
       Q99 <- factor(Q99, 
                     levels=names(sort(table(Q99), 
                                       decreasing=FALSE))))})
     partii2=reactive({
     filter(dataa(), Q99 %in% input$parti, REGION %in% input$region)
})
     output$plot1=renderPlotly({
     input$action
     isolate(
        if(!is.null(input$parti) && !is.null(input$region) && input$genre=="Tous"){
        if((length(input$region))==1)
         {
           g <- ggplot(partii2(), aes(x = Q99, y =(..count..)/sum(..count..)))
           g <- g + geom_bar(fill="#0f00ee") + labs(title=paste("Vote dans la région de", input$region,"pour",input$parti,sep = " ")) +labs(x="Parti politique", y="")+coord_flip()+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+ theme_bw()+theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white"))
           }
      else{
        g <- ggplot(dataa(), aes(x = REGION, y =(..count..)/1200, fill=Q99))
        g <- g + geom_bar(position=input$position) + labs(title="vote") +labs(x=" ", y=" ")+labs(fill="Parti Politique")+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+ theme_bw()+theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white"))  +coord_flip() + geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/1200,3 )),y=(..count..)/1200 ),stat= "count", size=4, position = "stack")

         }
        }
       )
     })
   })
```

Ui

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(foreign)
  library(plotly)


  shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                  dashboardHeader(title = h4("Élections",style = "color:white"),

                                  titleWidth = 300 
                  ),
                  dashboardSidebar(id="", 
                                   tags$head(
                                     tags$script(
                                       HTML(
                                         "
                                         $(document).ready(function(){
                                         // Bind classes to menu items, easiet to fill in manually
                                         var ids = ['Enquête','dashboard','Prédiction','Données','Échantillon'];
                                         for(i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
                                         $('a[data-value='+ids[i]+']').addClass('my_subitem_class');
                                         }

                                         // Register click handeler
                                         $('.my_subitem_class').on('click',function(){
                                         // Unactive menuSubItems
                                         $('.my_subitem_class').parent().removeClass('active');
                                         })
                                         })
                                         "
                                       )
                                     )),
                                   sidebarMenu(
                                     menuItem(h4(strong("Enquête")), tabName = "Enquête",
                                              menuSubItem("Données",tabName = "Données"),
                                              menuSubItem("Échantillon",tabName = "Échantillon")),
                                     menuItem(h4(strong("Dashboard")), tabName = "dashboard"),
                                     menuItem(h4(strong("Prédiction")), tabName = "Prédiction"))

                                     ),



                  dashboardBody(
                    tabItems(
                      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",h2("Le comportement électoral des citoyens tunisiens", align="center",style = "color:blue"),


                              fluidRow(
                                tiltle="filtre",
                                column(width=4,
                                       box(
                                         title = "Filtre",
                                         status = "primary",
                                         width = 8,
                                         solidHeader = TRUE,
                                         background="navy", 
                                         box(

                                           solidHeader = FALSE,
                                           width = 8,
                                           background = "navy" ,
                                           radioButtons("genre", "Genre", c("Homme","Femme","Tous"),"Tous")

                                         ),

                                         box(
                                           solidHeader = FALSE,
                                           width = 12,
                                           background = "navy",
                                           selectizeInput("region", label = "Région",
                                                          choices = levels(pff$REGION), 
                                                          selected = "Ariana", multiple=TRUE)


                                         ),

                                         box(
                                           solidHeader = FALSE,
                                           width = 12,
                                           background = "navy",
                                           selectizeInput("parti", label = "Parti politique",
                                                          choices = levels(pff$Q99), 
                                                          selected = "CPR", multiple=TRUE)


                                         ),
                                         box(
                                           actionButton("action","Mettre à jour!"),
                                           #submitButton("Mettre à jour!",icon("refresh")),
                                           background = "navy"


                                         )





                                       )





                                ),


                                box(
                                  solidHeader = FALSE ,width = 8,height = 500,
                                  collapsible = TRUE,align="center",
                                  radioButtons("position", "", c("fill","stack"), selected = "fill", inline = TRUE, width = NULL),
                                  plotlyOutput('plot1', height = 400,width = "100%")

                                )

                              )# end of fluidrow



                      )

                         ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? I changed the server side a little, according to this question here: [Convert ggplot object to plotly in shiny application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663854/convert-ggplot-object-to-plotly-in-shiny-application)

Also, each time a relevant user interaction takes place, the input are being shown in the console by the server.

```
observeEvent(c(input$action,input$position), {
    output$plot1<-renderPlotly({
      getGgplot <- function(inputObj){
        g <- ggplot(data.frame())
        if(!is.null(inputObj$parti) && !is.null(inputObj$region) && inputObj$genre=="Tous"){
          # generate proper ggplot
          if((length(inputObj$region))==1)
          {
            g <- ggplot(inputObj$partii2, aes(x = Q99, y =(..count..)/sum(..count..)))
            g <- g + geom_bar(fill="#0f00ee") + labs(title=paste("Vote dans la région de", inputObj$region,"pour",inputObj$parti,sep = " ")) +labs(x="Parti politique", y="")+coord_flip()+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+ theme_bw()+theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white"))
          }
          else{
            g <- ggplot(inputObj$dataa, aes(x = REGION, y =(..count..)/1200, fill=Q99))
            g <- g + geom_bar(inputObj$position) + labs(title="vote") +labs(x=" ", y=" ")+labs(fill="Parti Politique")+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+ theme_bw()+theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white"))  +coord_flip() + geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/1200,3 )),y=(..count..)/1200 ),stat= "count", size=4, position = inputObj$position)
          }
        }
        return (
          g
        )
      }
      inputs <- list(
        "parti" = isolate( input$parti ),
        "region" = isolate( input$region ),
        "genre" = isolate( input$genre ),
        "position" = input$position,
        "dataa" = dataa(),
        "partii2" = partii2(
          partiArg = isolate( input$parti ),
          regionArg = isolate( input$region )
                            )
      )
      print("inputs:")
      print(str(inputs))
      g <- getGgplot(inputs)

      # return ggplot to ggplotly
      print(
        ggplotly(g)
      )  
    })
  })
```

There seem to be some other issues with your code also, but I was not really able to figure out what the problem is. I.e., I received the following warning when situation "Genre = Tous, Region = Ariana and Parti politique = CPR, JabhaChaabia":

```
Warning in if (nchar(p$labels$title %||% "") > 0) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So here is my comprehensive code, what do you say?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(dplyr)
library(foreign)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

pff <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
                 REGION Q99 Q101
                  Tunis  Nahdha Femme
                  Tunis Jabha Femme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Femme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
                  Tunis           CPR Femme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Femme
                  Tunis        Autres Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Homme
                  Tunis Jabha Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Homme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Femme
                  Tunis JabhaChaabia Homme
                  Tunis        Autres Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Tunis Jabha Femme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Tunis        Autres Homme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Femme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Homme
                  Tunis        Autres Femme
                  Tunis Jabha Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis           CPR Femme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Homme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Femme
                  Tunis           CPR Homme
                  Tunis           CPR Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Tunis        Autres Homme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Homme
                  Tunis  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Tunis        Nahdha Femme
                  Tunis        Autres Femme
                  Tunis  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Femme
                  Ariana           CPR Femme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Femme
                  Ariana  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Ariana           CPR Homme
                  Ariana  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Homme
                  Ariana  Nepasvoter Femme
                  Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Ariana           CPR Homme
                  Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Ariana           CPR Femme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Femme
                  Ariana           CPR Femme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Homme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Homme
                  Ariana           CPR Homme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Homme
                  Ariana  Nepasvoter Homme
                  Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Ariana  NidaaTounes Homme
                  Ariana        Nahdha Homme    ')

dataa<-function(){
  return (
    within(as.data.frame(pff), 
           Q99 <- factor(Q99, 
                         levels=names(sort(table(Q99), 
                                           decreasing=FALSE)))
    )
  )
}

partii2<-function(partiArg,regionArg){
  return(
    filter(dataa(), Q99 %in% partiArg, REGION %in% regionArg)
         )
}

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(c(input$action,input$position), {
    output$plot1<-renderPlotly({
      getGgplot <- function(inputObj){
        g <- ggplot(data.frame())
        if(!is.null(inputObj$parti) && !is.null(inputObj$region) && inputObj$genre=="Tous"){
          # generate proper ggplot
          if((length(inputObj$region))==1)
          {
            g <- ggplot(inputObj$partii2, aes(x = Q99, y =(..count..)/sum(..count..)))
            g <- g + geom_bar(fill="#0f00ee") + labs(title=paste("Vote dans la région de", inputObj$region,"pour",inputObj$parti,sep = " ")) +labs(x="Parti politique", y="")+coord_flip()+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+ theme_bw()+theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white"))
          }
          else{
            g <- ggplot(inputObj$dataa, aes(x = REGION, y =(..count..)/1200, fill=Q99))
            g <- g + geom_bar(inputObj$position) + labs(title="vote") +labs(x=" ", y=" ")+labs(fill="Parti Politique")+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+ theme_bw()+theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white"))  +coord_flip() + geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/1200,3 )),y=(..count..)/1200 ),stat= "count", size=4, position = inputObj$position)
          }
        }
        return (
          g
        )
      }
      inputs <- list(
        "parti" = isolate( input$parti ),
        "region" = isolate( input$region ),
        "genre" = isolate( input$genre ),
        "position" = input$position,
        "dataa" = dataa(),
        "partii2" = partii2(
          partiArg = isolate( input$parti ),
          regionArg = isolate( input$region )
                            )
      )
      print("inputs:")
      print(str(inputs))
      g <- getGgplot(inputs)

      # return ggplot to ggplotly
      print(
        ggplotly(g)
      )  
    })
  })
})
ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                            dashboardHeader(title = h4("Élections",style = "color:white"),
                                            titleWidth = 300 
                            ),
                            dashboardSidebar(id="", 
                                             tags$head(
                                               tags$script(
                                                 HTML(
                                                   "
                                                   $(document).ready(function(){
                                                   // Bind classes to menu items, easiet to fill in manually
                                                   var ids = ['Enquête','dashboard','Prédiction','Données','Échantillon'];
                                                   for(i=0; i<ids.length; i++){
                                                   $('a[data-value='+ids[i]+']').addClass('my_subitem_class');
                                                   }
                                                   // Register click handeler
                                                   $('.my_subitem_class').on('click',function(){
                                                   // Unactive menuSubItems
                                                   $('.my_subitem_class').parent().removeClass('active');
                                                   })
                                                   })
                                                   "
                                                 )
                                               )),
                                             sidebarMenu(
                                               menuItem(h4(strong("Enquête")), tabName = "Enquête",
                                                        menuSubItem("Données",tabName = "Données"),
                                                        menuSubItem("Échantillon",tabName = "Échantillon")),
                                               menuItem(h4(strong("Dashboard")), tabName = "dashboard"),
                                               menuItem(h4(strong("Prédiction")), tabName = "Prédiction"))
                                               ),
                            dashboardBody(
                              tabItems(
                                tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",h2("Le comportement électoral des citoyens tunisiens", align="center",style = "color:blue"),
                                        fluidRow(
                                          tiltle="filtre",
                                          column(width=4,
                                                 box(
                                                   title = "Filtre",
                                                   status = "primary",
                                                   width = 8,
                                                   solidHeader = TRUE,
                                                   background="navy", 
                                                   box(
                                                     solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                     width = 8,
                                                     background = "navy" ,
                                                     radioButtons("genre", "Genre", c("Homme","Femme","Tous"),"Tous")
                                                   ),
                                                   box(
                                                     solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                     width = 12,
                                                     background = "navy",
                                                     selectizeInput("region", label = "Région",
                                                                    choices = levels(pff$REGION), 
                                                                    selected = "Ariana", multiple=TRUE)
                                                   ),
                                                   box(
                                                     solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                     width = 12,
                                                     background = "navy",
                                                     selectizeInput("parti", label = "Parti politique",
                                                                    choices = levels(pff$Q99), 
                                                                    selected = "CPR", multiple=TRUE)
                                                   ),
                                                   box(
                                                     actionButton("action","Mettre à jour!"),
                                                     #submitButton("Mettre à jour!",icon("refresh")),
                                                     background = "navy"
                                                   )
                                                 )
                                          ),
                                          box(
                                            solidHeader = FALSE ,width = 8,height = 500,
                                            collapsible = TRUE,align="center",
                                            radioButtons("position", "", c("fill","stack"), selected = "fill", inline = TRUE, width = NULL),
                                            plotlyOutput('plot1', height = 400,width = "100%")
                                          )
                                        )# end of fluidrow
                                )
                              ))))
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Comment: The input reactions work now as you requested. I decided to work with `observeEvent()` and isolate the data inputs (please check the server console messages). I am not sure about the plotting though, Please work on that, should not be too hard. :)

Comment: Thank you very much @nilsole
it's working but it's more complicated than i thought, actually my dashboard it's more complicated than that I have about 14 plots and each plot has about 50 lines of code so it's difficult to introduce all these changes :( I just made a small exemple.
Can I put  the renderPlotly of all the diffrent plots inside the same observeEvent function ?

Comment: Yes you can of course. :) just a matter of routing and storage. As you see, I put several inputs into the observeEvent function. You can, for instance, insert even more and update only those outputs affected. :)

Comment: Ok thank you very much :))) @nilsole it's gonna take w long time becauce I have about 3000 lines of code but i'll try :D

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect `g$labels`, what do you see?

It looks like you are allowing multiple selections for input parti.

The paste statement for the title is most likely picking these up and giving you more than one title, which is what the error is stating.

You can make the parti vector a character by wrapping it in an additional paste statement with `collapse=","` or by making all the inputs into the original paste a vector `c("My title is",c(1,2))` with `collapse=" "`.

```
labs(title=paste("Vote dans la région de", inputObj$region,"pour",paste(inputObj$parti,collapse=","),sep = " "))
```